# Commercial use of a tutorial with CC-BY-NC-SA license

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I have an online programming tutorial published with CC-BY-NC-SA license.

Does the NC (Non-Commercial) mean that no one may print it and sell as a book?

Does it mean that no one may publish it on their website and put ads to get money from it?

P.S. And, for what it's worth, if I accept contributions from other people, how can I ensure that I still can do what I described here? Sell/put ads/do whatever I do when the book is fully mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many argue that "NC" doesn’t allow someone selling the work or using advertisements next to it, but [some argue](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/11574/105) that "NC" does allow selling/advertisements as long as no profit is made.

The license itself doesn’t seem to define it clearly. See:

- Creative Common’s FAQ [Does my use violate the NonCommercial clause of the licenses?](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#does-my-use-violate-the-noncommercial-clause-of-the-licenses)
- Creative Common’s wiki page [NonCommercial interpretation](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/NonCommercial_interpretation)

If you include contributions which are licensed to you under *CC BY-SA-NC*, you [have to follow the license yourself](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5761/138). You may only ignore the license if you are the sole copyright holder or if you got the permission from the contributors (they could license their contributions under a compatible license to you, they could accept [a CLA](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5804/138), etc.).